# Having trouble installing the most recent version of awswrangler on conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, aws-data-wrangler

My current conda environment is running python 3.8.5.

When I look at their [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/awswrangler/), it shows that the newest version is 2.5.0. For some reason, when I initially installed it via `conda install -c conda-forge awswrangler`, it installed version 0.3.1.

When I try to run :

conda install -c conda-forge awswrangler==2.5.0

It has issues solving the environment.

[image: version 0.3.1]

Answer (score 0):

There was [an issue](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler/issues/593) in AWS Data Wrangler with incompatible dependencies, but this has now been solve.  Can you try and build your environment again and see if the issue has now been fixed?

Thanks

Nick